# Подготовка входных данных для нейросети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras, tensorflow

Хочу реализовать предсказание курса акций на фондовом рынке. Я понимаю, что в нейросеть напрямую не может поступать, например, стоимость акции, ибо нужна какая-то предварительная обработка. Как я должен подготовить данные на примере массива стоимостей акций (реализую сеть в keras+tensorflow)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил нормализовать путем деления тренировочных и тестовых выборок на максимальное значение

Answer (score 0):

Если вы собираетесь использовать данные OHLC или технических индикаторов, вам желательно нормализовать данные прежде чем прогонять через ИНС. Из моих наблюдений для этого больше подходит Min-max scaling. 
Ps: [Другие способы нормализации](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics))